# How to use XAMPP on Ubuntu?

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-12.04, xampp

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 today and I would like to use XAMPP on this OS.

I downloaded the installation file, extracted that in Opt directory and tried to start it from the terminal. It started fine from the terminal. To edit my files, I downloaded Geany. Now when I try to save file through this text editor in the htdocs folder of XAMPP, it says "Permission Denied". It was also not allowing me to make a subfolder in htdocs but I made that through Terminal. I want to know how to save the file?

Please give me some additional commands too (like deleting files, renaming files..). Would I need to type in commands in Terminal for everything I need to do in this Root directory?

Comment: did you have "root" access in the terminal (sudo su)? permissions...

Comment: @Logman Yeah I have the root access

Comment: you installed Xampp with root, but you are trying to edit those files when you are not. Usually you do not edit the htm file directly but thru http/ftp... change the user access rights to files or run Geany with root access (dangerous)....